# How to bind a default value from observable array to dropdown?

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I have a dropdown and data binded to it as below

**HTML:**

```
 <div>
                        <label>Notice Type</label>
                        <select id="ntctype" data-bind="options: NoticeType, value: selectedNoticeType, optionsCaption:'Choose...', optionsValue:'NoticeTypeID', optionsText:'NoticeTypeDescription'"></select>
                    </div>
```

**KO JS:**

```
  self.NoticeType = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.selectedNoticeType = ko.observable();
        $.getJSON("GetNoticeType", null, function (data) {
        self.NoticeType(data);
            }
    );
```

the NoticeType array looks like this
[{"NoticeTypeID":1,"NoticeTypeDescription":"Close"},{"NoticeTypeID":2,"NoticeTypeDescription":"Open"}]

I would like to set the deafult value as **Close** after binding.I tried using optionsAfterRender & ko.applybindingstoNode none of them worked.

What would be the clean and neat approach to do this?

Comment: you can simply try self.selectedNoticeType(1) should work . working fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/7u7qebr5/12/ . cheers

Comment: I tried this but not working as the observable array is loaded after my getJSON

Comment: well then once your getJSON is executed . after you assign data to `self.NoticeType` then do `self.selectedNoticeType(1)` . it will work

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/7u7qebr5/13/ . that should help you .

Comment: Yes it does work but does not show up as default value in the dropdown.I can currently work around this but just wanted to know why

Comment: Thanks @supercool please update your jsfiddle as answer ill mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you just need to set default value to `value` binded observable in viewModel

**View Model :**

```
function accountViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.NoticeType = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedNoticeType = ko.observable();
    self.ajaxcall = function () {
        self.NoticeType([{
            "NoticeTypeID": 1,
            "NoticeTypeDescription": "Close"
        }, {
            "NoticeTypeID": 2,
            "NoticeTypeDescription": "Open"
        }]);
        self.selectedNoticeType = ko.observable(1);
    }

    self.ajaxcall();
}
```

Working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/7u7qebr5/13/)**